# Would it even make sense to write a C# compiler that targets LLVM?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, llvm

I'm thinking about writing a small C# compiler.

One idea I've been toying with is writing a subset of the C# grammar, say up to 2.0 for ANTLR.    Then, using this to target the LLVM and write a native code compiler for C#?

Does this idea even make sense or would this not work?  Would there be any way to still make calls to the BCL?

I know there is the [CCI (Common Compiler Infrastructure)](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) which would aid me in simply generating .NET executables.  But I'm curious if what I said above would be possible?

Comment: I do not know .NET's internals well enough to really help you, but as far as I know it shouldn't be any kinda problem except for calling external .NET assemblies

Comment: Define "small". The specification is *five hundred pages* long.

Comment: @Eric Lippert,  Mike Stall, who I believe is on your compiler team, wrote a relatively "small" C# compiler called "Blue" that is able to bootstrap itself as his first C# program.

Comment: Indeed; Mike used to have the office next to mine. Unfortunately he is no longer on the compiler team, though he is still in the division.

Answer (score 18):

[Mono already can be used with a LLVM backend](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_LLVM).

[More details in the Mono docs](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime:Documentation:LLVM).

Check out the Limitations section, though.

UPDATE: as of Mono 2.8 the LLVM backend has graduated to stable. See the [Mono 2.8 release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8).

Answer (score 4):

Beyond Mono already cited, Microsoft is working in its own implementation called [LLILC](https://github.com/dotnet/llilc) (it isn't just an experiment). So it makes much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to rewrite the entire standard library, too, it would be better to find a different project, if you're just looking for something to do.  A possibility would be to write a .NET bytecode compiler or an IL assembler.